# error: package androidx.core.app does not exist when running flutter blue plugin

Tags: android-studio, flutter, bluetooth, dependencies, androidx

I'm working on Flutter and use Flutter blue plugin. 
Everything ran well at the beginning but suddenly the program can't perform build because of flutter blue plugin version.

```
    dependencies:
      vector_math: any
      path_provider: ^1.3.0
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      flutter_map:
      flutter_blue: ^0.6.3+1
      cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```

this is the error message

```
    C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_blue-0.6.3+1\android\
    src\main\java\com\pauldemarco\flutter_blue\FlutterBluePlugin.java:43:
    error: package androidx.core.app does not exist import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
    ^
    error: package androidx.core.content does not exist
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `fullter_blue` version `0.6.3+1` has these types of compatibility issues. I prefer you to use the `flutter_blue 0.6.2` version as it is most stable and working correctly as per my own experience.

```
dependencies:
...
flutter_blue: 0.6.2
```

Comment: Just as a note to other: Don't include the ^ if you want to use 0.6.2 thus the code will be `flutter_blue: 0.6.2`

Comment: @PouncingPoodle what does the ```^``` imply?

Comment: @S.Ramjit It implies that you would use the most recent release of that library.

Comment: After changing it to 0.6.2, I got this warning though - flutterblue/FlutterBluePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems like the author (@pauldemarco) is not maintaining and releasing the `flutter_blue` plugin. See this issue

- https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/510

It also seems like several people have moved to use a fork on github (maintained by @boskokg)

- https://github.com/boskokg/flutter_blue

I have not tried the fork myself (yet).